# Mysql search on multiple join results

Tags: mysql, search, join

I've a table "products" and a table where are store some attributes of a product:

```
zd_products
----------
|ID|title|
----------
| 1| Test|
| 2| Prod|
| 3| Colr|
```

zd_product_attached_attributes

```
------------------
|attrid|pid|value|
------------------
|1     | 1 | A   |
|2     | 1 | 10  |
|3     | 1 | AB  |
|1     | 2 | B   |
|2     | 2 | 22  |
|3     | 2 | BB  |
|1     | 3 | A   |
|2     | 3 | 10  |
|3     | 3 | CC  |
```

I want to search in zd_products only the products that have some attributes values, for exam place
Get the product when the attribute 1 is A and the attribute 3 is AB
Get the product when the attribute 2 is 10 and the attribute 3 is CC
etc

How can i do this using a join ?

Comment: I know the join syntax... my problem is when i want to check in more join results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Oh, the Joys of the EAV model!*

---

One way is to use a separate JOIN operation for each attribute value. For example:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.title
  FROM zd_products p
  JOIN zd_product_attached_attributes a1 
    ON a1.pid = p.id
   AND a1.attrid = 1
   AND a1.value = 'A'
  JOIN zd_product_attached_attributes a3 
    ON a3.pid = p.id
   AND a3.attrid = 3
   AND a3.value = 'AB'
```

With appropriate indexes, that's likely going to be the most efficient approach. This isn't the only query that will return the specified result, but this one does make use of JOIN operations.

Another, less intuitive approach

If `id` is unique in the zd_products table, and we have guarantee that the `(attrid,pid,value)` tuple is unique in the `zd_product_attached_attributes` table, then this:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.title
  FROM zd_products p
  JOIN zd_product_attached_attributes a
    ON a.pid = p.id
   AND (  (a.attrid = 1 AND a.value = 'A')
       OR (a.attrid = 3 AND a.value = 'AB')
       )
 GROUP
    BY p.id
     , p.title
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

will return an equivalent result. The latter query is of a form that is particularly suitable for matching two criteria out of three, where we don't need a match on ALL of the attributes, but just some of them. For example, finding a product that matches any two of:

- color   = 'yellow'
- size    = 'bigger'
- special = 'on fire'

And of course there are other approaches that don't make use of a JOIN.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** And if I want to the same but using `OR` operator? I mean get ONLY if the attribute 1 is A or the attribute 2 is AB otherwise don't select the record.

**A:** A query of the form like the second one in my answer (above) is more conducive to the `OR` condition.

If you want XOR (exclusive OR), where one of the attributes has a matching value but the other one doesn't, just change the `HAVING COUNT(1) > 1` to `HAVING COUNT(1) = 1`. Only rows from products that find one "matching" row in the attributes table will be returned. To match exactly 2 (out of several), `HAVING COUNT(1) = 2`, etc.

A query like the first one in my answer can be modified to use OUTER joins, to find matches, and then do a conditional test in the WHERE clause, to determine if a match was found.

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.title
  FROM zd_products p
  LEFT
  JOIN zd_product_attached_attributes a1 
    ON a1.pid = p.id
   AND a1.attrid = 1
   AND a1.value = 'A'
  LEFT
  JOIN zd_product_attached_attributes a3 
    ON a3.pid = p.id
   AND a3.attrid = 3
   AND a3.value = 'AB'
 WHERE a1.pid IS NOT NULL
    OR a3.pid IS NOT NULL
```

I've just added the `LEFT` keyword, to specify an outer join; rows from products will be returned with matching rows from a1 and a3, along with rows from products that don't have any matching rows found in a1 or a3.

The `WHERE` clause tests a column from a1 and a3 to see whether a matching row was returned. If a matching row was found in a1, we are guaranteed that the `pid` column from a1 will be non-NULL. That column will be returned as NULL only if a matching row was not found.

If we replaced the OR with an AND, we'd be negating the "outerness" of both joins, making it essentially equivalent to the first query above.

To get an XOR type operation (exclusive OR) where we find one matching attribute but not the other, we could change the WHERE clause to read:

```
 WHERE (a1.pid IS NOT NULL AND a3.pid IS NULL)
    OR (a3.pid IS NOT NULL AND a1.pid IS NULL)
```

Comment: You going to do the solution using `Having Count(*) = 2` as well?

Comment: It's really the only way ? :(

Comment: @Lwyrn: I meant to say the first query in my answer demonstrates `:a way:` (one way out of several ways) that use a `JOIN` operation. And there are several ways that don't use a `JOIN` operation.

Comment: And if I want to the same but using or operator ? I mean get ONLY if the attribute 1 is A or the attribute 2 is AB otherwise don't select the record

Answer (score 1):

### Use a pivot

You can do this type of query using a **pivot**.  As far as I know, MySQL doesn't have a native, built in pivot, but you can achieve this by transposing the rows and columns of your `zd_product_attached_attributes` table using:

```
SELECT pid, 
MAX(CASE WHEN attrid = 1 THEN value END) `attrid_1`, 
MAX(CASE WHEN attrid = 2 THEN value END) `attrid_2`,
MAX(CASE WHEN attrid = 3 THEN value END) `attrid_3`
FROM zd_product_attached_attributes
GROUP BY pid
```

This will pivot your table as shown:

```
+----+---------+-------+      +----+----------+----------+----------+
| attrid | pid | value |      | pid| attrid_1 | attrid_2 | attrid_3 |
+----+---+-------------+      +----+----------+----------+----------+
|  1     |  1 |   A    |      |  1 |    A     |    10    |    AB    | 
|  2     |  1 |   10   |  =>  |  2 |    B     |    22    |    BB    | 
|  3     |  1 |   AB   |      |  3 |    A     |    10    |    CC    |
|  1     |  2 |   B    |      +----+----------+----------+----------+
|  2     |  2 |   22   |      
|  3     |  2 |   BB   |      
|  1     |  3 |   A    |
|  2     |  3 |   10   |
|  3     |  3 |   CC   |
+--------+---------+---+
```

So you can select the products id and title using:

```
SELECT id, title FROM zd_products
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT pid, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN attrid = 1 THEN value END) `attrid_1`, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN attrid = 2 THEN value END) `attrid_2`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN attrid = 3 THEN value END) `attrid_3`
    FROM zd_product_attached_attributes
    GROUP BY pid
) AS attrib_search
ON id = pid 
WHERE ( attrib_1 = 'A' AND attrib_3 = 'AB' )
OR ( attrib_2 = 10 AND attrib_3 = 'CC' )
```

Note: You can use this type of query when you have guaranteed uniqueness on (pid, attrid)

(thanks @spencer7593)

Comment: This will work if we have guaranteed uniqueness of the `(pid,attrid)` tuple. This approach would need to be adjusted if an attribute can be multivalued, e.g. if a product can be both `color=blue` and `color=yellow`. (This is one of the benefits of the EAV model, handling multivalued attributes.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Good point. Based on the OP's sample data, I assumed a unique attrid + pid key.

Comment: (+1 on your answer, because it's a workable approach to converting from EAV back to "normal" relational tuple.) When I make assumptions is when I get burned; when I assume something is unique (cuz it looks like it should be and appears to be from a sample), but the real answer to the question "is this unique" turns out to be "most of the time it is".  I'm not gonna assume until I see the CONSTRAINT defined and enforced in the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work:

```
select title
from zd_products p
join zd_product_attached_attributes a ON a.pid = p.id
where ( attrid = 1 and value = 'A' )
or ( attrid = 3 and value = 'AB' );
```

If you want to tack on more "searches" you could append more lines similar to the last one (ie. or "or" statements)

Comment: Nope, it can't work, because using the "or" operator if the attrid 3 has AB and the attrid 1 not have A the record get selected

Comment: @JamesG: this is close. If we have some guaranteed uniqueness (of the `(pid,attrid,value)` tuple in `zdpaa` and `id` and/or `name` in `zdp`, we could add a `GROUP BY` clause and a `HAVING COUNT()` clause. This technique is particularly effective for matching two or out of three attribute values, for example.